# How to exit the windows command prompt in which a java application got started

Tags: java, console, cmd

How to exit the console of a simple Java program after displaying an error message?

currently my code has:

```
...
...
if (some condition){
//print error
System.exit();
...
...
```

But this `System.exit();` leaves the console open. I have tried `exit(0);`, `System.exit(0);` as well.

Comment: In what way doesn't it help? What happens when you run `System.exit()`?

Comment: It should do the trick. So either you never actually execute System.exit or you are doing something relevant which is not present in the code. Please create a small as possible example for which you can post the complete code here, or at least tell us more about what kind of stuff your app doing.

Comment: @Jens Schauder: It's a simple Java program that I'm executing on Windows cmd. I want the cmd to automatically close after displaying the particular error message.

Comment: Hang on - do you want to close the Command Prompt window or just exit your program? I presume the condition is getting hit and you're printing the error OK?

Comment: @Edd: Yes. Only the error is getting printed. How to close the cmd.exe automatically after printing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting to close the Command Prompt window that your application is running in, then I don't believe there is a way to do it (At least not nicely).

Why do you want to start your application from the command prompt and then close the pre-existing Command Prompt window? This will surely get rid of the error message that you're outputting (unless it's also being logged - in which case why print it to a window you want to close?).

This is Windows specific, but would creating a shortcut in Windows Explorer to `java -jar MyJarFile.jar` or `java MyCompiledClass` do what you want? Instructions for this sort of approach can be found [here](http://www.cs.armstrong.edu/liang/radjb5/wwwCreateShortcutforJavaApplicationsonWindows.pdf).

Comment: Okay. So, I can finally stop searching on Blogs and Google. Thanks.

Comment: The problem was that you weren't wanting to exit your program. You were wanting to kill the environment in which your program was running in.

Answer (score 2):

`System.exit(1);`

should work fine. Note that if you're exiting with an error, you would normally set a *non-zero* exit code. From [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29):

> The argument serves as a status code; by convention, a nonzero status
>   code indicates abnormal termination.

This means you can script using common conventions, any process spawning your program can react correspondingly etc.

Comment: It's a simple Java program that I'm executing on Windows cmd. I want the cmd to automatically close after displaying the particular error message

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to run your program in a command prompt and if the program fails you want it to display the error message, close the program AND the commad prompt window?

If this is the case then the only thing I could think of would to be to run your program in a batch file that checks the exit status of your program. So in your code write your error message, then I suggest sleep for a few seconds so the user can actually see it, then exit with status code 1.e.g.

```
if(SomeCondition){
  System.err.println("ERROR MESSAGE...");
  Thread.sleep(3000);//Sleep for 3 seconds... 
  System.exit(1);
}
```

Then run your program from a batch file which checks the "ERRORLEVEL" environment variable e.g.

```
java <INSERT_PROGRAM_NAME>
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 exit
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.System` doesn't have an `exit` method with no parameters, so `System.exit();` would be a compile-error. (`System.exit(1);`, however, would be fine.) The reason that your code isn't working is probably that you're not recompiling it, so you're still running some old version from before you added that line.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are trying to install firefox .bat file from java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        String[] command = { "cmd.exe", "/C", "Start", "C:\\firefox.bat" };
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).waitFor();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Execution error");
    }
}
```

This would trigger the command prompt and the window will be opened until you manually go and close it after the firefox is installed.

The fix is that in your .bat file just after your command just put an "**exit**" For eg:

Your firefox.bat would contain

@Start /wait "Firefox" "C:\Firefox Setup 41.0.exe" -ms

exit

This will close your command prompt window. Hope this helps...

Answer (score -1):

have a look at the below link

http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/jot/decisions/exercise11/exit.html

*There is a general convention that a program must return an exit code. The exit code should be zero to indicate success, and non-zero to indicate failure. Platforms differ about what different non-zero codes mean, so programmers often just return 1 as a general indication of failure.*

Answer (score -1):

System.exit(); terminates the JVM. The int is the status code (0 means "normal" exit). If it's not exiting it's because that part of your code is not reachable and not being executed at all.

[Java API - System.exit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29)

Comment: It's a simple Java program that I'm executing on Windows cmd. I want the cmd to automatically close after displaying the particular error message